# Criar popup DOM

Tags: javascript

Estou a criar uma nova pagina popup atraves do codigo JavaScript. A pagina não existe, por isso quero que seja apenas uma pagina temporaria. Exemplo:

```
    if (option == 3){
        var myPopup = window.open("", "", "width=350, height=300");
        myPopup.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log("received load event");
        }, true);
    }
```

Essa popup so aparece atraves de uma checkbox. Como posso adicionar elementos a pagina, como input text, buttons, etc

Comment: Não tem como, para fazer isso você deve criar um novo arquivo html e no `window.open` apontar para essa url. Uma boa opção de uso para substituir o que quer fazer é utilizar o `modal` da bootstrap ou o `dialog` da jquery ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akm, se realmente precisa abrir uma nova janela, acredito que o melhor é criar um documento em memoria com o HTML desejado:

```js
var tmplPopUp = document.getElementById("tmplPopUp");
var abrirPopUp = document.getElementById("abrirPopUp");

abrirPopUp.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var blobPopUp = new Blob([tmplPopUp.innerHTML], { type: 'text/html' });
  var urlPopUp = URL.createObjectURL(blobPopUp);
  var popUp = window.open(urlPopUp, "", "width=350, height=300");
  
  popUp.addEventListener("load", function (event) {   
    var label1 = popUp.document.getElementById("label01");
    var label2 = popUp.document.getElementById("label02");
    var enviar = popUp.document.getElementById("enviar");    
    
    console.log(label1, label2, enviar);
  });  
});
```

```html
<input id="abrirPopUp" type="button" value="Abrir PopUp" />

<template id="tmplPopUp">
  <div>
    <label>
      Label 01:
      <input id="label01" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Label 02:
      <input id="label02" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" />
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
```

O Codigo acima não vai funcionar devido uma limitação do SO, você pode ver o mesmo funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/wknt2fy0/1/)

Caso precise adicionar elementos no PopUp apos o mesmo ser carregado, você pode manipular o `document` do mesmo.

```js
var tmplPopUp = document.getElementById("tmplPopUp");
var abrirPopUp = document.getElementById("abrirPopUp");

abrirPopUp.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var blobPopUp = new Blob([tmplPopUp.innerHTML], { type: 'text/html' });
  var urlPopUp = URL.createObjectURL(blobPopUp);
  var popUp = window.open(urlPopUp, "", "width=350, height=300");
  
  popUp.addEventListener("load", function (event) {   
    var label1 = popUp.document.getElementById("label01");
    var label2 = popUp.document.getElementById("label02");
    var enviar = popUp.document.getElementById("enviar");    
    
    var label3 = {};
    label3.div = popUp.document.createElement("div");
    label3.label = popUp.document.createElement("label");
    label3.textNode = popUp.document.createTextNode("Label 03: ");
    label3.input = popUp.document.createElement("input");    
    
    label3.input.id = "label03";
    label3.input.type = "text";
    label3.label.appendChild(label3.textNode);
    label3.label.appendChild(label3.input);
    label3.div.appendChild(label3.label);
    enviar.parentNode.insertBefore(label3.div, enviar);
    
    var label3 = popUp.document.getElementById("label03");
    console.log(label1, label2, label3, enviar);
  });  
});
```

```html
<input id="abrirPopUp" type="button" value="Abrir PopUp" />

<template id="tmplPopUp">
  <div>
    <label>
      Label 01:
      <input id="label01" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Label 02:
      <input id="label02" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" />
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
```

No exemplo acima, adicionei um terceiro input... novamente, caso queira ver o mesmo funcionando, terá de conferir o [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/wknt2fy0/2/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funciona perfeitamente. Editei o jsfiddle, e não consigo fazer algo com o button dentro do template. exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/wknt2fy0/6/

Comment: @akm, o conteudo do template não é renderizado pelo Browser, portanto você não pode pesquisar conteudo DOM dentro do mesmo, ele serve apenas para que o JavaScript utilize ele como modelo para a criação de outros elementos DOM... neste caso você terá de adicionar o evento ao `input#enviar` dentro do `popUp`... segue exemplo [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wknt2fy0/7/)

Comment: Obrigado, estou tentando fechar o popup (template), assim que carregar no button. Utilisei o window.close(); dentro o addEventListener click mas não fecha a janela.